# Flash Builder 4.6 - error without path, can't trace

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have to work with decompiled code, I had only few original files, so I replaced them, fixed all errors, warnings. Finally, I have this:

[image: flex-errors]

Why? What might be wrong? Those errors are like pointing to nowhere. I've checked every file, line by line, but no clue. Seems like all imports are correct.

Comment: I suspected imports at first too, b/c it's complaining about a unknown property named "com". But notice that you have binding expressions in your MXML that use fully qualified package names of classes. The problem could be on one of those lines somewhere. Also, the packages are "com.abc.catchmentdetox.whatever" but the "com" package in your project explorer seems to be empty. There does seem to be another project named "catchmentdetox" but that is closed. So what are those binding expressions referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I decided that this information I supply is not enough, so I made further research. Actually, flash develop showed this error: "_com_abc_catchmentdetox_ui_panels_ActivityInfoPanelWatcherSetupUtil.as" - this file can not be founded anywhere in the src folder. Not with search or something like that. Though, I can see this file inside flash decompilator. I wonder, how it might be connected? How come, Flash Builder seees and uses this file, but I can not find it anywhere referenced at all?

Comment: The file name (`_com_abc_catchmentdetox_ui_panels_ActivityInfoPanelWatcherSetupUtil.as`) makes it sound like that class is one that the Flex compiler generates when compiling your project, in this case it's related to binding. Flash Builder normally deletes them after compiling. You can keep the files by adding "-keep" or "keep-generated-actionscript" to your project's compiler options. It's likely the error is in your  some variable/property name in one of your MXML curly brace expressions in the "AcitvityInfoPanel" component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was internal Flash Builder error. I resolved it, removing all hardcoded pathes from class, like: com.blablabla.blablalba.class.getSomeFunction()